# Kubernetes cloud agent for Jenkins always offline during pipeline execution

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I try to deploy microservices into k8s pod using Jenkins pipeline and k8s cloud agent.
I configured my agent on Jenkins but during execution I always have message saying my agent is offline.

You could find my Jenkins configuration and my Jenkins file.

Regards,

Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        MAVEN_SETTINGS = ''
        MAVEN_ENV = 'maven-3.6.3'
        JDK_ENV = 'jdk-1.2'
        GIT_URL = 'PRIVATE REPO'
    }
    agent any
    parameters{
        booleanParam(name:"RELEASE",
           description:"Release",
           defaultValue:false
        )
    }
    stages {
        stage ('build & deploy'){
            when{
                expression {!params.RELEASE}
            }
            steps{
                withMaven(
                    maven: env.MAVEN_ENV,
                    mavenSettingsConfig: env.MAVEN_SETTINGS,
                    jdk: env.JDK_ENV) {
                        sh "mvn clean deploy -U"
                }
            }
        }
        stage ('create image'){
            steps{
                script {
                    docker.withRegistry('https://registry.digitalocean.com', 'images-credential') {
                        def customImage = docker.build("images-repo:${params.IMAGE_VERSION}","./target")
                        customImage.push("${params.IMAGE_VERSION}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage ('Deploy Pod') {

            agent { label 'kubepod' }

            steps {
                script {
                    kubernetesDeploy(configs: "/kubernetes/pod.yml", kubeconfigId: "mykubeconfig")
                    kubernetesDeploy(configs: "/kubernetes/services.yml", kubeconfigId: "mykubeconfig")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Kubernetes agent config
[image]

Pod template config
[image]

Jenkins global security config
[image]

Build log
[image]

Comment: Can you see logs from your agent pod?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use `TCP port for inbound agents: Fixed and put 50000`

Comment: I change my jenkins configuration an relaunch the pipeline but i have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to create direction connection.Please go to Kubernetes cloud details and add your service token and ssl of that token to make connection. you have a issue in your pipeline.Please correct it like

```
stage(test){
  agent{
    cloud 'cloud name'
    yaml"""

    """

  }
}
```

Please follow this [article](https://medium.com/swlh/quick-and-simple-how-to-setup-jenkins-distributed-master-slave-build-on-kubernetes-37f3d76aae7d) to start from the basic details.